# Power Query: How to get conditional running total?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerbi

| A header | Another header | RUNNING TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | NULL | 0 |
| 5 | 1234 | 5 |
| 5 | NULL | 5 |
| 5 | NULL | 5 |
| 5 | 5678 | 10 |
| 5 | 9012 | 15 |

Let's say I have access to the first two columns in Power Query. How would I go about getting the running total?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([Another header] <> null) then [A header] else 0
```

Doesn't exactly answer the question but it's the code I was after.

Comment: Please explain what it does and doesnt do.